# change global variable on given date

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables

I guess, this is a very simple question. I want my wordpress theme to automatically change some global variables on a given date.

My Theme changes color and some other things every two months. From now on, I want to type in the needed variables before that date and let Wordpress do the changes. I could do that from within the loop, so that the first person who enters the site on that date initiates the change. But that would mean extra code, everytime the loop is called. Is it possible to perform that task automatically?

Comment: if date < datenow then theme = this else theme = that...

Comment: My question is where to put this code. Into the functions.php? Is there a way to let wordpress do this without the user doing something? I dont understand very much about PHP.

Comment: P.S.: It's a little bit more complicated than just changing the theme on that date.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used WP in ages, but I think this will work, change time_to_change_theme to the forward date you want. I have no idea where to put this, I am sure you will work it out though.

```
<?php

$time_to_change_theme    =   strtotime("2012-12-31 12:12:12"); // the time in the future you want to change the theme
$time_now = strtotime(now);

if($time_to_change_theme > $time_now)
{
   echo "Use current theme";
}else{
    echo "Change theme";
    update_option('current_theme', '[theme name]'); // this should update the current theme
}

?>
```

Uses code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348092/1169669) by [harmen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176603/harmen)

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your reply. What I wanna do, is not changing the theme, just some variables for color and textual elements. I know, how to ask for current time eg. I just dont know how to manage an automatic change.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6285699/1169669 this may provide some idea of how to change the css maybe

Comment: Made it this way. I wont accept the answer, because it isnt, what I asked for, but thank you very much.